# Are recursive geometric sequence with second term solvable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the following recursive formula:

$$ U_n = a U_{n-1}+f(n) $$

For $f(n)=b$ ($f$ independent on $n$), it is possible to find the analytic expression for $U_n$. My question is: Are there analytic expression of $U_n$ for an arbitrary $f(n)$ ?

Comment: You'll get $$U_n = a^nU_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{n-k}f(k)$$ Getting a more closed formula than this depends on $f.$

Comment: Possibly a better closed formula: $$a^n\left(U_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f(k)}{a^k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the recurrence $$f_{n}=a_n+b_nf_{n-1}\qquad n\ge1,\ \  f_0\text{ given}.$$
Set $B_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}b_k$, and divide through by $B_n$. We get
$$\frac{f_n}{B_n}=\frac{a_n}{B_n}+\frac{f_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}}.$$
Setting $F_n=f_n/B_n$ and $A_n=a_n/B_n$, $$F_m-F_{m-1}=A_m.$$
Sum both sides from $m=1$ to $n$:
$$F_n-F_0=\sum_{m=1}^{n}A_m,$$
which is
$$f_n=f_0B_n+\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_m\frac{B_n}{B_m}$$
which can be simplified more if desired.